# im new to c++ and i was trying to call make a class constructor that take 2 classes as its parameter

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double Default = 0;

class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(double x, double y, double z);
    double X, Y, Z;
    double fVctr[3];
};

Vector::Vector(double x,double y,double z)
{
    this->X = x;
    this->Y = y;
    this->Z = z;
    this->fVctr[0] = X;
    this->fVctr[1] = Y;
    this->fVctr[2] = Z;
}
```

this part throws me the error no default constructor esists

```
class Edge
{
public:
    Vector vectA;
    Vector vectB;
    Edge(Vector _vectA , Vector _vectB){
        this->vectA = _vectA;
        this->vectB = _vectB;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector Vertex(0,2,5);



    // Debug
    cout << Vertex.X <<"\n"<< endl;
    cout << Vertex.Y << "\n" << endl;
    cout << Vertex.Z << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a constructor

```cpp
Constructor( ... ) 
{ // A
  ...
};
```

at Point A, all members are getting default initialized, since they cannot be uninitialized, when we start into the code of the constructor. To initialize members without default constructor or `const` members, you have to use the so-called [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

In your example this would look like this:

```cpp
Edge(Vector _vectA, Vector _vectB) : vectA(_vectA), vectB(_vectB) 
{ // This can be empty, since everything is done, but it has to exist nonetheless. 
}
```

It is good practice to use the member initializer list for as much as possible, since you can save yourself some default initializations and every member is in the state it should be before you do anything with it.

PS: You don't have to reference members by `this->member`, just write `member`. Also, please do not use `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is in your Edge class Constructor.

```
Edge(Vector _vectA , Vector _vectB){
    this->vectA = _vectA;
    this->vectB = _vectB;
}
```

the Arguments need a default value. for this, you can Overload your constructor in Vector class.

like this :

```
Vector::Vector(double x=0,double y=0,double z=0)
{
    this->X = x;
    this->Y = y;
    this->Z = z;
    this->fVctr[0] = X;
    this->fVctr[1] = Y;
    this->fVctr[2] = Z;
}
```

or like this :

```
Vector::Vector()
{
    this->X = 0;
    this->Y = 0;
    this->Z = 0;
    this->fVctr[0] = X;
    this->fVctr[1] = Y;
    this->fVctr[2] = Z;
}
```

As a matter, of course, you didn't use the Edge class in Main Procedure. so you can safely delete or comment that class and prevent the compile error of your code.